# Convert 1D to 2D with c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a problem with converting points within 1D to 2D image, and vice versa. At the moment there are no problems when the image examined is a square. However, it doesn't work for the rectangular images. (i.e. `width` is not equal to `height`)

```
    // dimension of image
    int width = image.rows; // width
    int height = image.cols; // height

    std::vector<float> vertici_1;
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
        for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
            vertici_1.push_back( float(y*width+x) ); // from 2D to 1D
    ...
    cv::Point((index1/width), (index1%width)); // from 1D to 2D
```

Comment: It'd be useful if you showed example data, in original and desired formats.  It looks odd that you are putting the "flat index" into your float vector, but you didn't really say what you want.  Do you mean to put the data corresponding to (x,y) into the float vector?  Also, is this column major or row major?  You may have reversed your x and y in the conversion from 1d to 2d.

Comment: the data is taken from the image I load in my program. For example a 173x139 image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are incorrectly placed for 2D to 1D transformation. If you intend to store the same row of image as consecutive elements of the vector `vertici_1`, then the loop for which the loop variable is `y` should be the outer for loop.

```
std::vector<float> vertici_1;
for(int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
        vertici_1.push_back( float(y*width+x) );
```

Alternatively, if you intend to store the elements of the same column as consecutive entries to `vertici_1` (i.e. as it currently *is* in your code) then you should do the 1D to 2D transformation as follows.

```
cv::Point((index1 % height), (index1 / height));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    enum {N=4,M=5,SZ=N*M};
    const int one_d[SZ]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int two_d[N][M] ;
    memcpy(two_d[0],one_d,SZ*sizeof(int));
    for( int i=0;i<N;i++){
       for(intj=0;j< M;j++){
         cout<< two_d[i][j]<<" ";
       }
       cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is always good, but you also need to provide some context or explanation of what it's doing and how it solves the problem.